# pubspec.yaml deprecated layout

Tags: dart

Here is my `pubspec.yaml`.

```
name: oct
version: 0.1.0
description: >
  Ojus Chemistry Toolkit (OCT) is an open-source toolkit for solving a
  variety of cheminformatics problems.  It is developed in Dart, mostly.
dependencies:
  args:
    sdk: args
```

When I run `pub install`, I receive a warning as follows.

```
Warning: Package "oct" is using a deprecated layout.
```

Reading `pub`'s package layout details, I have not yet understood what is triggering the above warning.  Request help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have some .dart files outside predefined directories:

```
lib
web
test
```

New SDK gives a helpful link if this problem occurs: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/pub-package-manager/package-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Lesiak is mostly right. You'll get this warning if pub finds any `.dart` files in your package's root directory. In the old layout, that was where you put your publicly importable files.

In the new layout, those should go under `lib`.